# Is there a way to detect which tests are inside a boost unit-test binary

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost-test

is there a way to detect which tests are inside a boost unit-test binary? The goal would be to present some kind of user interface to select the tests that need to be run. I checked the exports of the dll created with

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
```

but I didn't find anything self-explaining. And the documentation only mentions that you can create sophisticated test runners - but not how.

regards
Tobias

Comment: I'm not sure about the value of presenting a menu to the user, but +1 nonetheless.

Comment: have you ever seen nunit test-runners or test-integrations into an IDE? That's what you need it for.

Comment: I have not, but I guess that makes sense.

Comment: check for example this picture - it illustrates the use case quite nicely: http://bbltest.sourceforge.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Screen-shot-2011-03-03-at-8.56.10-AM.png You can run your tests individually if required and you easily see what failed without switching from your IDE - perfect for TDD.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be helpful: [getting all boost test suites / test cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385011/getting-all-boost-test-suites-test-cases/36461218#36461218). It suggests using a global fixture, which provides a hook extend the user interface.