# getting all boost test suites / test cases

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, boost-test

As the title says, I want to get all test suites or test cases (name) from a test application, ether in the console or as xml output. 
Test framework is the boost test library.

Is there an option to achieve this? I did not found anything useful in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done without much intrusion using a [global fixture](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/fixtures/global.html). Assuming you have a translation unit (cpp file) that contains `main` explicitly or auto generated, you can intercept test execution when a certain command line argument is provided. Then you can traverse the test tree using a customized visitor, which lists all available tests. Here is a small working example, which creates a test runner by compiling and linking files `main_test.cpp`, `a.cpp` and `b.cpp`:

**main_test.cpp**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// --- Boost Includes ---
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTestSuite
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

using namespace boost::unit_test;

struct Visitor : test_tree_visitor
{
  size_t level = 0;

  void visit( test_case const& test )
  {
    std::string indentation( level, '.' );

    std::cout << indentation << test.p_name << std::endl;
  }

  bool test_suite_start( test_suite const& suite )
  {
    std::string indentation( level, '.' );
    level++;

    std::cout << indentation << "Suite: " << suite.p_name << std::endl;
    return true;
  }

  void test_suite_finish( test_suite const& suite )
  {
    level--;
  }
};

struct GlobalFixture
{
  GlobalFixture( )
  {
    int argc = framework::master_test_suite( ).argc;
    for ( int i = 0; i < argc; i++ )
    {
      std::string argument( framework::master_test_suite( ).argv[i] );

      if ( argument == "list" )
      {
        Visitor visitor;

        traverse_test_tree( framework::master_test_suite( ), visitor );

        exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
      }
    }
  }

};

BOOST_GLOBAL_FIXTURE( GlobalFixture )
```

**a.cpp**

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE ( TestA )

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE ( TestFoo )
{
  BOOST_CHECK(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE ( TestBar )
{
  BOOST_CHECK(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END() // TestA
```

**b.cpp**

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE ( TestB )

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE ( TestFoo )
{
  BOOST_CHECK(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE ( TestBar )
{
  BOOST_CHECK(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END() // TestA
```

Invoking the runner without any arguments results in

```
./somelib_testrunner1 
Running 4 test cases...

*** No errors detected
```

Passing the argument `list` used in the fixture defined above results in

```
Suite: MyTestSuite
.Suite: TestA
..TestFoo
..TestBar
.Suite: TestB
..TestFoo
..TestBar
```

Answer (score 6):

There is simply the [--list_content](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/utf_reference/rt_param_reference/list_content.html) command line option, exactly for that purpose.

Comment: Introduced (i.e. documented) in [Boost 1.59](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/utf_reference/rt_param_reference/list_content.html).

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there is no easy way to do this without actually running the tests.

And even then the only thing coming to my mind without touching the code would be `--log_level=test_suite` and some sort of parsing script that finds the "Entering test suite", "Leaving test suite" and "Entering test case" messages (or parsing the xml given when you also put `--log_format=XML`, if you have a xml parser at hand).

But even that spoils the log with your added `BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE`s and of course encountered errors and warnings.

Seeing how the boost test framework is not much more than a bunch of macros, defined in the header, you could of course add the functionality yourself, probably easiest by adding another log format just listing the suites and tests, assuming you are fine with running the tests while finding the list.